# IOS- App crash while access Google Analytics Instance in custom framework with iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Actually, I have created a custom framework. I am using Google Analytics in the main project and in the custom framework (That I have created) as well. When I am trying to get GAI(Google AnalyticsInstance) object in my custom framework the app is crashing. Although It is working fine with iOS 11 but crashed on iOS 10.

Exact line where I am getting crash: GAI.sharedInstance().

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the crash log?

Comment: try going through this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850192/google-analytics-sdk-ios10